# Dafactory V2 Copy Activity Json

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to copy json file from one blob to another using the datafactory copyactivity and need to Set custom value for one of the property in the dest Json when copying... so I was trying to set the jsonPathDefinition as shown in the link below to then use expression like this "@{parameters('myNumber')}" ...but seems in the C# library it is not available... is not going to be available as it available in V1 library ..is it deprecated in V2 or something that has been missed or there are other ways to achieve this in V2. Please suggest....

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/data-factory/supported-file-formats-and-compression-codecs#json-format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In V2, there is a defect whose fix is on the way and should be available in about one week.  The temporary workaround is using REST API.